# How to ignore first value and first comma in comma separated string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I am having a simple comma separated list of values.

All I want to do is to ignore first value and first comma from the list

```
'Hello1, Hello2, Hello3, Hello4'
```

I want result as `'Hello2, Hello3, Hello4'`

I want to ignore `'Hello1'` and First `','`

Comment: Consider [normalizing your table into 1NF](https://www.1keydata.com/database-normalization/first-normal-form-1nf.php) -- values should be atomic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stuff()`:

```
select stuff(str, 1, charindex(',', str + ',') + 1, '')
```

Storing lists of things in strings usually indicates that something is wrong with the database design.  You should be storing these values in separate rows of a table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
select ltrim(stuff(col, 1, charindex(',', col), ''))
```